# A3 Drawing Template

Tags: tikz-pgf, paper-size, posters

I'm trying to create a method/workflow for the batch creation of A3 drawings using LaTeX.

I issue drawings that look like this:
[image: Example Drawing]

Most of the information on the right never changes, only the Title, Drawing No. and Revision No. On the left there's two pictures, each with a short description underneath.

There are a set number of these drawings that we use and typically I issue only some of them for any one project. The drawings must be A3 size.

What I'm trying to build is likely a LaTeX main file into which I can write all the info that will be the same for each drawing e.g.

- Project
- Project Number
- Date
- Issuer
- etc

And then a command that adds a drawing to the document in a customisable way based on input commands e.g:

```
\addDrawing{Drawing_Number, Drawing_Revision, Thing1_Title, Thing1_text, Thing1_image, Thing2_Title, Thing2_text, Thing2_image}
```

To begin with, I please need help creating this drawing template in LaTeX. I have tried using the 'standalone' class, but abandoned it because I didn't think it's the right class for this. I then used 'tikzposter' but it doesn't do A3 (as far as I could figure out) so I dropped that.

I'd appreciate any input as to the best way to create these drawing templates and how to add the pictures and text for "Thing1" and "Thing2"

Many thanx in advance.

Comment: Also, please provide the code you've got so far e.g. whatever you use to 'issue' such a drawing at the moment. Nobody is going to want to type out all the bits and bobs for the different boxes by manually copying from your image and they shouldn't need to, since you could easily provide text to copy-paste.

Comment: Is it a poster? If not, why tag it that way? Do you particularly need Ti*k*Z/PGF? If so, why? If not, why the tag? `standalone` is not the right class in my opinion. I'd use `article` with the `geometry` package and may something like `eso-pic` or `flowfram`. Would have a fiddle, were there something to fiddle with. But there isn't, so I obviously shan't.

Comment: Samcarter - Good idea, I'll do that. cfr - Currently, the drawings are made in MS Word, which is why I am looking for a better/more efficient way of doing it. Drawing is also a bit of a loose term, but the most applicable I could think of. All it is, is a document showing two methods of construction for example for wall junctions, that depend on the type of thing being constructed.

Comment: You might find some inspiration here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410893/

Answer (score 3):

Since posting, I've come up with the following method solution. I made the drawing template in inkscape, import it and add text over in latex using Tikz.

Here's the blank template. 
[image: Blank Drawing Template]

And an example where I just add a title.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[a1paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Define commands
\newcommand{\drawing}{}
\newcommand{\drawingTitle}{}

\newcommand{\makeDetail}[2]{
    \renewcommand{\drawing}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\drawingTitle}{#2}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{\drawing}};
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0] at (35.8,5.8) {\huge{\drawingTitle}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

     \makeDetail{drawing_example}{A Name Here}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: Drawing with Title]

I admit, it is not the most elegant solution. Placing the text correctly and matching the font and font size is a bit of a pain, but I reckon I only have to go through that process once.

Using the same method, I can then add Thing1 and Thing2 as required.