# package chemfig does not work with tikzlibrary circuits.pid.ISO14617

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, tikz-circuit-lib, tikzlibrary

Using `tikz` and have a document with various libraries.
In particular `\usetikzlibrary{circuits.pid.ISO14617}`
works fine until I add `\usepackage{chemfig}` with `\chemfig`

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.pid.ISO14617}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\section{Process and Instrumentation Diagram}
\tikz [circuit pid ISO14617] \draw (0,0) to [pump={displacement}] (2,0);

\section{chemical}
\chemfig{O-C-O}

\end{document}
```

Gives error:
`./chemfig-test.tex:11: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function C (in C\tikzcircuitssizeunit of ().`

Essentially I would like to use both `\chemfig` and `\tikzlibrary{circuits.pid.ISO14617}` which currently do not appear to work together.

EDIT: UPDATE:
The tikzpgfmanual section 54 covers externalizing graphics.
Using the example provided I was able to concoct the following partial solution.

```
% This is the file chemfigProb
        \documentclass[]{article}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{circuits.pid.ISO14617}
        \usepackage{chemfig}
        \pgfrealjobname{chemfigProb}
        \begin{document}
        \section{Process and Instrumentation Diagram}
        \beginpgfgraphicnamed{process-1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikz [circuit pid ISO14617] \draw (0,0) to [pump={displacement}] (2,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \endpgfgraphicnamed
        \section{chemical}
        \chemfig{O-C-O}
        \end{document}
```

Step1: commenting out lines: \usepackage{chemfig} \chemfig{O-C-O}
Step2: Run Command Prompt> xelatex --jobname=process-1 chemfigProb.tex
Step3: commenting out line: \usetikzlibrary{circuits.pid.ISO14617} and reintroducing the commented lines in Step1
Step4: Run Command Prompt. xelatex chemfigProb.tex

Returns the bottom half of the process with the pump and a model of carbon dioxide, however, This gives only the bottom half of the symmetry pump process.

https://gitlab.com/peer23peer/PIDcircuitTikZ/issues/14

[image: Output]

Comment: Is `circuits.pid.ISO14617` an official library? The only reference of it I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410893/121799), and this suggest it is not.

Comment: @marmot yes, that is where I found out about this package. Perhaps my lack of knowledge of official libraries as opposed to unofficial libraries. I did not realize that this was perhaps not official. In any case, if it is not official would it be possible to get it to work? If not how can I know what is official and what is not?

Comment: @jelle-spijker Hi Jelle, would you know if this can be rectified. I really like the package you made.

Comment: @CJD nice to hear that you like the package. Yes this is a home-brew unofficial package, still under development. If you could create an issue ( https://gitlab.com/peer23peer/PIDcircuitTikZ/issues ) I will check/fix if it is a bug in my code.

Comment: @JelleSpijker would a possible solution to my dilemma be to use the circuits.pid.ISO14617 package to create a separate document with only the figure and then to embed that into my master document? If so, how might I do this?

Comment: @CJD That would certainly be possible and an easy fix for you. You could use the standalone package for this. I have identified that the problem is indeed somewhere in my code. Rest assured you are not forgotten, but I'm a bit short on time at the moment. Working a regular job and writing a thesis in my spare time, takes up a lot of time.
If some of the more experienced LaTeX coders could help, that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @JelleSpijker I have updated the question with a partial solution. Ideally, it may work, however, only seeing half the process is now the issue.