# TikZ: Piping and instrumentation diagram (P&ID) shapes available?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, shapes, circuits, structure

To draw electrical wiring schemes in `TikZ` the nice package [circuitikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz) is available.

However, is there something similar existent for drawing piping and instrumentation diagrams?

**Example of such a diagram:**

[image: Screenshot of the desired package shapes]

Further description on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piping_and_instrumentation_diagram). Something like this would be awesome to create more complex system schemes with several devices while preserving common `LaTeX`-precision. I think in German language those graphics are called "R&I-Fliessschema".

---

Edit: Hereby I do **not** ask someone to draw this picture for me! I just ask if there is some package available which delivers the mentioned elements as predefined shapes maybe.

Comment: @Down-Voters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: This scheme can be drawn with  TikZ with lot of effort.  For some simple elements you can use predefined shapes, other you need to drawn for example as `pic` pictures. Task is quite demanding, since TikZ is not intended for drawing such images and for its elements doesn't exist specialized libraries (as far as I know). For more help you need to show what you try so far, otherwise I afraid that question will be closed as "to broad".

Comment: This would be a major undertaking, but each step is fairly simple.  It is easier to create new components using circuitikz (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm).  OTOH, you might want to just copy the central engine and replace all the existing components.

Comment: A P&ID library was introduced by its author, Jelle Spijker, here: [Chemical process flow sheets TikZ/PGF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410893/). The available shapes are here: https://gitlab.com/jellespijker/PIDcircuitTikZ/blob/master/example.pdf.

Comment: @Ross why not add a small example mwe block as an answer ?

Comment: @Ross: Wow, very nice! Thank you very much! I can really share the comment of KJO - a MWE would be a great answer!

Comment: By the way: Why isn't PIDcircuitTikZ an official package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a package to produce process flow diagram with TikZ. These are slightly less complex than P&IDs, but you can work it out something useful anyway. At least, the package defines a certain variety of symbols commonly used in chemical process diagrams. You may want to have a look to the chemplants package, available on CTAN at https://ctan.org/pkg/chemplants

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any other answers I am including a screenshot from using the P&ID Library myself

[image]
using example from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410893/170109

Note when I was a draughtsman/checker I would have rejected better diagrams.
As a pure novice in TikZ I know my rendering could be much better, however as a time served Drawing Office Manager who **has** drawn such diagrams in many non CAD formats (e.g. Typewriters and Word Processors) **I would not recommend TikZ for P&ID production by humans**. Some process flow diagrams can be done by tiling and it may be possible to adapt TikZ to produce "Mimics" in an automated work flow but the overheads needed to make corrections would likely outweigh any benefits (its tough enough using dedicated CAD systems)