# What do I need to change to get rid of the "Package PGF Math Error"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Through [TikZ: Piping and instrumentation diagram (P&ID) shapes available?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487454) I found the neat `PIDcircuitTikZ` library. However if I want to compile the example from https://gitlab.com/jellespijker/PIDcircuitTikZ/-/blob/master/example%20draft%20drawing.tex I run into an issue reported a long time ago (https://gitlab.com/jellespijker/PIDcircuitTikZ/-/issues/16) and I want to fix it.

However I am already struggling with the error itself:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `input' (in 'input in'). ..., anchor=input in] at ($(D1)+(1.5,0)$) {};
```

To me it seems that the "input in" must have been an anchor defined by TikZ or circuitikz which is now gone. Am I right? But what can I change or where should I start to look how to fix this?

Comment: If I'm seeing this right, the shape that will be used for the `regenerative pre-heater`, the `2518 ISO14617` shape, doesn't define `input in` ([anymore](https://gitlab.com/jellespijker/PIDcircuitTikZ/-/commit/c2ce125397b5d322b2ad3feb491367802d0414ad)). There's `cold in` and `hot in` as well as as plain `cold` and `hot` and the `out` variants. Neither the examples nor the manual reflect that change, though.

Comment: Also, that (nice!) package seems to be based on the Ti*k*Z circuit library, so it's quite probable it'll be incompatible with `circuitikz`...

Comment: That seems the case and I meanwhile found other points where the doc differs from the code. But this is a starting point for me, thanks @Qrrbrbirlbel

Comment: Well @Rmano I am not relying on `circuitikz` so it would be fine, if it works standalone.

Comment: @TobiBS yes, my comment was related to the fact that you tagged the question `circuitikz` 

Comment: I see @Rmano and this was then by accident. I was mislead by the package name, but you are right, it uses circuits instead.